# CiviEvent online registration not working with Stripe payment processor

Tags: wordpress, civievent, stripe

I've just recently started working with CiviCRM so please bear with me.
I'm organising an event with CiviEvent. I have an online registration form which works great until I enable Stripe as a payment processor. As soon as I do that, when I enter in all the form details, payment details, and hit continue, the page just reloads without the form submitting or the payment going through. For testing purposes I tried using PayPal and I have the same issue. What am I doing wrong? Please, I would like to fix the Stripe issue over the PayPal issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated! 

Stripe extension version 5.4.1 
Wordpress version 5.2.2 
Theme X version 6.5.5

**UPDATE:** 
OK, so I was getting so frustrated by all of this that I decided to create a subdomain with a clean install of WordPress, civicrm, and not use a fancy theme, just in case.

**Errors now via Chrome:** 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () civicrm_stripe.js:1

and upon page reload: 
 
GET https://example.org/register/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/js/civicrm_stripe.js?r=auxgf net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (index):1083

GET https://example.org/register/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/js/civicrm_stripe.js?r=auxgf net::ERR_ABORTED 404

**Errors now via Firefox:** 
The script from “https://example.org/register/wp-content/uplo…/ext/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/js/civicrm_stripe.js?r=rOabd” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.

Loading failed for the  with source “https://example.org/register/wp-content/uplo…/ext/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/js/civicrm_stripe.js?r=rOabd”. example.org:1051:1

​My new setup:
CiviCRM 5.16.1 
WordPress 5.2.2

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange!  Does it do the same thing if you use one of the standard themes?